# add a react button in this code with the function of updating data from database

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, discord, discord.js

I made a discord bot that sends an embed with data in it taken from mysql , but when I add the react function to update the database it always gives the following error `

```
        throw new DiscordAPIError(data, "code" in data ? data.code : data.error, status, method, url, requestData);
              ^

DiscordAPIError[10014]: Unknown Emoji
    at SequentialHandler.runRequest (D:\BotDc\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:667:15)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async SequentialHandler.queueRequest (D:\BotDc\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:464:14)
    at async REST.request (D:\BotDc\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:910:22)
    at async MessageManager.react (D:\BotDc\node_modules\discord.js\src\managers\MessageManager.js:242:5)        
    at async Message.react (D:\BotDc\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\Message.js:760:5)
    at async Query.onResult (D:\BotDc\index.js:48:11) {
  rawError: { message: 'Unknown Emoji', code: 10014 },
  code: 10014,
  status: 400,
  method: 'PUT',
  url: 'https://discord.com/api/v10/channels/745223942976962590/messages/1056802702929186836/reactions/1%3F%3F/@me'
}
```

`

and also when I only send embed without react on discord it will show error before embed is sent in pict
[pict](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9b7GE.png)

keep in mind I am sending multiple messages with 1 comands and mysql

her my code  `

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const mysql = require('mysql2');

const { token } = require('./config.json');

const client = new Discord.Client({ intents: [Discord.GatewayIntentBits.Guilds] });

const connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: 'localhost',
  user: 'root',
  password: '',
  database: 'continue_web'
});

connection.connect((err) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('Connected to MySQL database');
});

client.once(Discord.Events.ClientReady, c => {
  client.commands = new Discord.Collection();
  client.on(Discord.Events.InteractionCreate, async interaction => {
    if (!interaction.isChatInputCommand()) return;
    if (interaction.commandName === 'ping') {
connection.query("SELECT * , CASE sex WHEN 1 THEN 'Laki-Laki' WHEN 2 THEN 'Perempuan' END AS gender_text FROM accounts WHERE gauth_status='pending'", async (error, results) => {
  if (error) throw error;
  for (const result of results) {
    const exampleEmbed = new Discord.EmbedBuilder()
      .setColor(0x0099FF)
      .setTitle(result.nickname)
      .setURL('https://discord.js.org/')
      .setAuthor({ name: result.nickname , iconURL: 'https://continue-rp.my.id/forum/data/avatars/m/0/1.jpg?1671348397', url: 'https://discord.js.org' })
      .setDescription('Request Character Story')
      .addFields({ name: 'Story:', value: result.ucpmail , inline: false })
      .addFields({ name: 'Umur:', value: result.age + ' Tahun' , inline: true })
      .addFields({ name: 'Gender:', value: result.gender_text , inline: true })
      .addFields({
        name: 'Actions:',
        value: ':one: Approve\n:two: Reject',
        inline: true
      })
      .setTimestamp()
      .setFooter({ text: 'Character Dibuat:'+ '\n'+ result.create_date , iconURL: 'https://continue-rp.my.id/forum/data/avatars/m/0/1.jpg?1671348397' });
    await interaction.channel.send({ embeds: [exampleEmbed] });
  }
});

    }
  });
  console.log(`Ready! Logged in as ${c.user.tag}`);
});

client.login(token);
```

`

I've tried various methods such as reply, but can only send 1 message, which I expect can update the database using React

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58461388/discord-bot-returning-unknown-emoji-error-for-default-unicode-emojis.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/Q2kHaZJ

same